# Cassandra installation on Windows cannot, getting error "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine"

Tags: java, cassandra

I am trying to install cassandra version 3.11.14 o windows and i get this error:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have the JAVA_HOME, PYTHON_HOME and CASSANDRA_HOME paths on my system env.

Comment: what Java version?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Verify your version of Java with the following command:

```
java -version
```

Cassandra 3.11 will only run on Java 8.  If you want to run Cassandra 4.x (not supported on Windows), you can go as high as Java 11.

> I have Java version 20, because it works with Spark. for my project, I need Spark, Kafka, pycharm, and Cassandra and I am working on Windows, if I will download Java version 8 could I work with all of the above together, or that it will damage Spark?

You might want to check on the JRE requirements for Spark for that.  But you could use something like [JEnv](https://github.com/FelixSelter/JEnv-for-Windows) to default to specific JRE versions on a per-directory basis (that's what I do).  Then you could specify Java 8 for your Cassandra directory, and default to Java 20 everywhere else.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response I really appreciate this.
I have Java version 20, because it works with Spark.
for my project, I need Spark, Kafka, pycharm, and Cassandra and I am working on Windows, if I will download Java version 8 could I work with all of the above together, or that it will damage Spark?

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted is too generic for us to provide a meaningful answer. Without the full error messages and details of your environment, the best we could do is guess at what the problem is.

As a friendly reminder, you need to provide sufficient information about the problem including things like software versions you're running, how you've configured the node, minimal steps to replicate the problem, and what research and troubleshooting you've done.

If you need guidance, I've published an article on the Apache Cassandra website that discusses [How to ask good questions](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community/ask_good_questions.html). Additionally, there is also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

For a bit of background, Cassandra 3.0/3.11 and earlier versions only supports Java 8. Cassandra 4.0 added support for Java 11 LTS ([CASSANDRA-9608](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608)) so C* 4.x will work with either Java 8 or Java 11. Support for Java 17 LTS will be added in a future release of Cassandra ([CASSANDRA-16895](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16895)).

Provided you are using Java 8, the JVM unable to start could be due to a long list of reasons. For example, if you have allocated too much of the system memory to the JVM heap then it won't be able to start if there is not enough memory left.

In any case, For what it's worth, the Java file I/O library that Cassandra uses has always been problematic on Windows particularly with NTFS. It has been a constant source of issues for users that we decided it wasn't good for the project to continue support (see the [discussion in this thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread/cpbpx74ysrs7xwgklpx2wh6003jms260)).

It has been so problematic that we dropped Windows support completely ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

For Windows users, the suggested alternatives are:

- Deploy [Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster with open-source [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) has a free tier where you can launch a cluster in just 5 clicks with no credit card required. Cheers!